# Added Array Value to New Array: After var_dump Value Disappears

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I am trying to add an array value to a new array like so:

```
$clientname[] = $cname['name'];
```

If I `var_dump($cname['name']);` then everything appears fine, but if I `var_dump($clientname);` I expect to see the same thing, but I don't, it appears as if I have done `var_dump($cname);`

The full code is here:

```
foreach($clientname as $client) {
                foreach($client as $cname) {
                var_dump($cname['name']);
                    $clientname[] = $cname['name'];
                    var_dump($clientname);
        }
        }
```

I have had to do the foreaches because of the array structure it  is in, obviously the `var_dump($cname['name']);` repeats for the amount of $cnames there is as expected

What can be causing my `$clientname` to be a duplicate of `$cname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the array you are looping through, you are adding values to itself?

In PHP, internally, it creates a copy of that array to loop through.
So if you would dump the array after the foreach'es, you would see the new values in it.

Why are you adding those values to the same array? Could it be more convenient to create a new array and add them to that?

This is how PHP works in the example, but if you can clarify the problem you are trying to solve, there may be better ways to solve it.

Comment: You've completely misunderstood, I am adding values to a NEW array, $clientname is a new array and I am adding the 'name' values of each associative array in '$client' to it.

Comment: foreach($clientname as $client) {
    ....
        $clientname[] = $cname['name'];

It looks like you are iterating through the new array and adding values to it.

Comment: Damn, I new it was obvious, not enough sleep you see! That's not what I was supposed to have done, I've just accidentaly named the  two variables the same! :P

Comment: If you var_dump($cname['name']), you see a string, which is an element of the array $cname.

If you var_dump($clientname), you see an array with one string inside it (the value of $cname['name'].

Since you are calling $clientname[] = ... you tell PHP to add it as an array value, that's what the brackets do.

It looks the same as $cname, because $cname is an array with one string inside, and you add that string to a new array, they look the same, but they are different.

If you want $clientname to be just a string, you could assign it like this.

$clientname = $cname['title'];

Comment: Yeah no it's fine, the only issue was I was accidentaly calling variables the same thing, if I call the second $clientname, $clientnames I will get what I want

Comment: Are you using an IDE? usually they point those mistakes out to you. Personally, i use PhpStorm.

Comment: No I don't really use IDE's, I use a text editor (one with a little more functionality so it will tell me about unclosed tags and stuff -- I use Notepad++)